# Add a boolean column indicating if an ID is associated with a particular value in a different column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, databricks

I want to add a boolean column that indicates whether or not an ID is connected to at least one Z value.

So this sample resembles my data set:

```
id | value
___________
1 | a
2 | b
2 | c
2 | Z
2 | Z
3 | d
4 | a
5 | Z
6 | a
7 | Z
```

This is the result I want:

```
id | hasZ
_________________
1 | false
2 | true
3 | false
4 | false
5 | true
6 | false
7 | true
```

But I'm stuck on how to get there. I know how to get the distinct id's that have TRUE, but I don't know how to combine them to get distinct true and false.

```
select distinct *
from (
  select id
    , CAST(CASE WHEN value = 'NULL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS boolean) AS hasZ
  from table1 
)
where hasZ = true
```

The above code that I have results in:

```
id | hasZ
_________________
2 | true
5 | true
7 | true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when value = 'Z' then 1 else 0 end) as has_z
from table1
group by id;
```

Note:  SQL Server does not have a *boolean* datatype, so this returns 0/1.